# About Data Import, Post-Process and Data Present. System Process Improvement

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, performance, import

I have a ASP.Net 3.5 web application. Both the website and SQL-Server are hosted on the `same server`.

The whole system is based on Numbers/Data, users need to `import` massive data to the system (e.g. using excel spreadsheet), the system needs to show the calculated figures `on screen` as well as generate `reports` for users.

Currently, there is an Import Server app running on this server, inserting/updating the data to `raw data tables`, then calculated the data and insert/update it to an `post-processed` table. All these processes are involved in `one thread` (could be in one Stored Procedure).

The drawback of this design is: the import app `costs` a lot of system resource and take a `long time` to run. It `locked` the table (e.g. TRANSACTION) and affected user's action on the website. Moreover, the calculated data are hard to be tracked and easy to be miscalculated.

I've tried to create a temp table (`View`) in the system to process the data on demand instead of post-processing it into calculated table. But I found the process time (View and SQL Stored Procedure `execution time`) is too long to be accepted (5 minutes or more, some query e.g. `join...between` or `apportion` annual data to daily takes the most processing time).

Hope some experienced guys could give me some advices (or general strategies) on how to improve the design/implementation for the system in all aspects, thanks.

All aspect includes: Multi-Servers, DBMS, Server Apps, Web Service, SQL Server Optimization, SQL Components, the whole system design and architecture etc.

Comment: wht's your architecture and used logiciels ? SSIS ? or other or specific program

Comment: @Aghilas Yakoub It is a n-tier application, using ADO.net in Data-Access-Layer . All data read/write relies on StoredProcedures. It's using SQL Server 2008. We are not good at database optimizations.

Comment: try to use SSIS. it's quick and made for data import

Answer (score 1):

So if I read the question correctly, you used to have this:

- System with raw data import + post processing. Two sets of tables.
- Web application suffers performancewise because post processing of raw data is time consuming and introduces locks in post processing tables where the web application reads the data.

Because of this, you are now experimenting with a setup where:

- Raw data is imported to one set of tables.
- Instead of post processing and storing the processed data, you are doing the post processing "on demand" in a view.
- This is not giving satisfactory performance either

How about trying an alternative version of your original setup? You could try a solution like this:

- Make *three* sets of tables
- One set for raw data import
- One set for storing results of raw data post processing
- And one set for storing a copy of the processed data.

This last set of tables would be used for generating reports. Using this setup, a "data import" would consist of three steps:

- Raw data import
- Post processing
- Update processed data to "live" tables.

Presumably, copying the processed data from one set of tables to another could be made reasonably performant. So the impact of data imports on the web application can be kept under control since the post processing will not directly touch the "live" tables.

Comment: Hi mate, have you come across this issue? Is this your real solution?thx.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following way

1st import the data to raw data table directly.

Then do the calculation in code behind instead of doing in stored procedure and this takes lot of time doing this in code behind will save database resource.

Once you are done with the calculation insert the calculated value to the calculated table.

Try to use the code behind as much as possible instead of database, use database only if something cannot be done in code-behind.

Comment: Do you mean a separated application will do the calculation and insert into the calculated table or my current Import Server App will do it. If code-behind process is handled by my current my current server app, it can be 5~10 times slower than running in StoredProc. Not sure about your mechanism.

Comment: OK, if you can not do the calculation in code behind then the only way is stored procedure optimization.

Or let me know more about how things are done.

Answer (score 0):

I see the join is taking a while can you confirm you have the foreign key in place.  Also if you show me the SQL I might be able to help.

Comment: Yes, table index and foreign are set up. It is not a pure join, heavy calculations are involved in the `select`. I think rewriting stored proc won't help too much, is there any advanced mechanism or component can be introduced to SQL Server in order to improve loading speed of the `view` ?